# Independent logging in multithreaded applications

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, logging

I'm currently debugging a multithreaded application (pthread under Linux ia64, ARM).
valgrind, helgrind, and gdb are my currently used tools.

There are some synchronizing issues and for later analysis,
I want to log thread execution to one or more files.

Naive implementation would do some write/fprintf which might
(depending on the libc implementation) lock some internal mutex.
That would in turn influence the program's behaviour
(I would call it 'locking by accident')
and is therefore not acceptable.

Searching the internet yields only to the inverse solution,
i.e. how to synchronize threads resp. how to log.
NB: Third-party logging libraries tend to garuantee multithread-safety
but not the opposite as described above.

So I came up with unsynchronized caching the log entries in memory,
on a per-thread basis, and flushing that to a file on program exit.

I guess that this is a general problem for many developers and
I wonder whether there is a **better** approach.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using a thread_local file descriptor for logging. For example `thread_local const int log = open(make_name(gettid()),...)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I do at program exit. For performance reasons writing is delayed.

Comment: This is not what is written in the question, neither what I propose. Instead of caching in memory, you open a log file for each thread at thread start up and then write directly, without any caching to the file. As each thread has its own file, the write will not cause inter-thread synchronization.

Comment: I dont completely understand what you mean by 'locking by accident', when you have multiple threads writing to the same file you need some form of synchronization (not just by accident)

Comment: 1. What I was missing is the guarantee that writing to two different streams does not interact at all. Thank your for enlightenment. 2. I tried to express that I'd like to know when there is an implicit synchronisation which makes a program work in the debug version (with logging) and might let it behave completely different in the release version (without logging).

Comment: What about the kernel? Does, in general, the system call "write" synchronize tasks?

Comment: Since you're running on Linux, POSIX guarantees that `write()` to a file opened in append mode is atomic.  `int logFD = open( name, ... | O_APPEND, mode );` Then just create a single C string and log it with `write( logFD, logStr, strlen( logStr ) );`  Just be sure to use `write()` and not `fwrite()` or `frprintf()` or `cout` or anything else.

Comment: 1. logging should be done infrequently, in order not to influence the application. That's why 3rd party log libraries doesn't care of it. Furthermore logging should be performed in real time, so you can monitor the application while running. In fact, log lines are usually flushed one-by-one, even if this has notoriously low-performance. It seems to me that you are not speaking of logging at all here - apart from this, your approach is fine with the data collection and past-end analysis.

Comment: With other words, the error I'm investigating in, is highly sporadic.
I suspect the error to vanish with logging because of an implicit synchronisation ("locking by accident").
There are two scenarios:
1. log to one stream: To ensure atomicity, libc's write() function must do some synchronisation. Bad for me.
2. log to multiple thread-specific streams: Since there is no concurrency, write() does not have to synchronize.
Now, does the **kernel** implement some synchronisation inside the system call?
If so, threads would get synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

Modern multi-thread safe high performance loggers normally:

- Provide a separate logging buffer for each thread, so that there is no locking involved when a thread writes a log message into the buffer (single-producer-single-consumer wait-free buffer).
- The log messages are binary, no `snprintf` or any other formatting happens in the thread that emits a log message. E.g. a log message is a copy of the format string and the arguments (the format string can be shallow-copied).
- Have a separate I/O thread that reads the binary logging messages from other threads, formats them and writes into the log file(s).
- The I/O thread does periodic polling on the logging buffers, so that no cross-thread messaging is required when emitting a log message. With an option for the message producer to notify the I/O thread to start writing out the log messages to the log file immediately (e.g. the logging buffer free space is getting low).

Comment: But the messaging will cause interthread-synchronisation and he wants to avoid that.

Comment: @Oliv Not necessarily. You can use polling.

Comment: The logger thread can have a lock-free, wait-free synchronization-free multi-producer single-consumer queue?

Comment: Do you have a link to a paper or the source code of such a queue, I am studying lock-free structure, that really interest me.

Comment: @Oliv I don't have a public source for you. This is somewhat tedious but not too hard to implement.

Comment: By polling, you mean the polling mechanism provided by the system call (epoll, poll, ...)?

Comment: @Oliv You wait on a condition variable with a timeout. When the condition variable is notified or timeout happens you check whether the logging buffers have new messages.

Comment: A ring buffer may overflow no? A logging message not consumed by a logging thread may eventually be erased if the logging thread wait too long.

Comment: @Oliv Correcto.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :).